# Make a POST request from standalone React to Django

Tags: reactjs, django, http, post, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a simple post request from the react server localhost:3000 to Django server localhost:8000 with axios. But I get 403 error.

I tried putting csrftoken in the headers but I am still getting the error.

How do you make a POST request from standalone React server to standalone Django server?

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const App = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

    function getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    const messageHandler = () => {

        const sentmessage = {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            message: message,
        }

        
            axios.post("/api/messages/",
                sentmessage,
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken

                    }
                },
            ).then((res) => console.log(res));
        
    }

    return (
        <div className="page">
            <div className="message_form">
                <p><textarea name="name" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter your name " /></p>
                <p><textarea name="email" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter your email " /></p>
                <p> <textarea placeholder="Enter your message here... " name="message" cols="30" rows="10" onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}></textarea> </p>
                <p><button className="sendbutton" onClick={() => messageHandler()}>Send</button></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can't access the cookies from the Django app since your React app is on a different domain/port. You need to use some other method of authentication, token or JWT for example

Comment: You have to install django-cors-headers first and configure it to accept requests comming from your react app without csrftoken.

Comment: @IainShelvington I tried fetching the csrftoken from django in react and then did a post request with fetched csrftoken. Still same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error. The error was because of the uncleared cookies.